# How to forbid modification of table rows except for triggers in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `accounts_balances` which is managed exclusively by triggers :

```sql
create table accounts_balances (
    account_id integer primary key references accounts(id) on delete cascade,
    balance integer not null
);

create or replace function new_account() returns trigger as $$
begin
    insert into accounts_balances (account_id, balance) values (new.id, 0);
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger new_account
after insert on accounts
for each row
execute procedure new_account();

create or replace function add_operation() returns trigger as $$
begin
    update accounts_balances
    set balance = balance + new.amount
    where account_id = new.creditor_id;
    update accounts_balances
    set balance = balance - new.amount
    where account_id = new.debitor_id;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger add_operation
after insert on operations
for each row
execute procedure add_operation();

-- etc ...
```

Is there a way to add policies to prevent someone to update this table manually ?

I tried :

```sql
alter table accounts_balances enable row level security;

drop policy if exists forbid_update on accounts_balances;
create policy forbid_update ON accounts_balances
for all
using (false);
```

but I can still do this :

```sql
update accounts_balances set balance = 0 where account_id = 10;
```

Comment: REVOKE is your best and most reliable friend. A superuser can always do everything, so you should never use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prevent SuperUsers from updating the Table-Contents, but an application shouldn't be connecting with a superuser, so no problem there.

Simply remove the Update-Privilege for the table for all roles and you should be good to go.

As your goal seems to prevent manual modifications you should also revoke INSERT and DELETE for the roles.

[PostgreSQL Documentation about privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html)

```sql
REVOKE UPDATE ON accounts_balances FROM public;
REVOKE UPDATE ON accounts_balances FROM role1;
REVOKE UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON accounts_balances FROM all;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Existing table rows are checked against the expression specified in USING, while new rows that would be created via INSERT or UPDATE are checked against the expression specified in WITH CHECK.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html

You don't have a WITH CHECK expression.

Comment: > if no WITH CHECK expression is defined, then the USING expression will be used